# Jquery AJAX CALL with parameter to controller's method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am working with Jquery AJAX Call in MVC Application. My view looks like this :

```
<p>

    Name @Html.TextBox("Name")
    Date @Html.TextBox("Date")
    <input type="submit" id="SubmitName" value="Submit" />
</p>
```

My AJAX call is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        var Details = JSON.stringify({
            StudentName: $("#Name").val(),
            DateofJoining: $("#Date").val()
        });
        $('#target').html('sending..');

        $("SubmitName").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/DQR/Details",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data : Details ,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#target').html(data.msg);
                },

            });
        })
    }
</script>
```

And my controller looks like this :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Details (string StudentName, string DateofJoining)
        {

            var result = (from dc in _db.Details
                          where dc.Name== StudentName
                          select dc.Address);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I don't know what I'm missing. The ajax request is not working. Could anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Imagining that ur controller name is DQR then you need to write as below:-

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/DQR/Details",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data : Details ,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#target').html(data.msg);
                },

            });
```

and id should be:-

```
 $("#SubmitName").click(function () {
        var Details = JSON.stringify({
        StudentName: $("#Name").val(),
        DateofJoining: $("#Date").val()
    });
    $('#target').html('sending..');

    //// your ajax call
}});
```

and what is Send()? i mean the click event should be under `$(document).ready(function() {});`

I would suggest take simple button rather than "submit" if you are playing client side with that.

Comment: Thanks @Neel.
I have made a change in that. But Still I couldn't get the request

Comment: put debugger; in code and check if it is called or not @Priya

Answer (score 1):

Bind click handler properly, move `Details` object creation in click handler

```
$(function() {
    $("#SubmitName").click(function () {
        var Details = JSON.stringify({
            StudentName: $("#Name").val(),
            DateofJoining: $("#Date").val()
        });
        $('#target').html('sending..');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DQR/Details",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data : Details ,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#target').html(data.msg);
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `$.post` method as well.

Here is an example.

```
var StudentName = $("#Name").val();
var DateofJoining = $("#Date").val();

$.post('/Controller/Action', { 'StudentName': StudentName , 'DateofJoining': DateofJoining  }, function(data) {
    $('#target').html(data.msg);
}, 'json');
```

Here is more information about [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)